# Error: no eligible device for app install

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I uploaded an app onto the app store. But my device is not seen when i click install no eligible devices for app install is shown. The manifest is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.igloo.readfifa"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.TypeSelection"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.playerquiz"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.playerquizmain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.teamquizmain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.leaguequizmain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.teamquiz"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.leaguequiz"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.shopcoins"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.BillingService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.BillingReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- NEW CODE BY AJITH -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <!-- Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="Register New Account"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.PredictionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_prediction"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.FixtureActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fixture"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.HistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fixture"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <!-- END OF CODE BY AJITH -->
        <!-- Ad Colony -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <!-- Ad colony -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.CoinShop"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_coin_shop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  >
        </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.Options"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
           >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.igloo.readfifa.About"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
           >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help. Also the app is not shown on typing the name in the store's search bar. It also shows that the app in incompatible with your device.

Comment: I think it must be a bug in Play Store. I've been getting the same problem, is says that the app I uploaded is not compatible with my devices, despite the fact that my devices are listed as being compatible in the developer console. I've emailed Google.

Comment: @joe_deniable . I have same issue, and i sent the email to Google too. But no response yet. 
Did you get any response or solution ?
Thanks